# It possible to show attributes from model to other attributes from model?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, underscore.js-templating

Hi i have a view with model attributes :

```
name: "P",
surname: "a",
sorters: ["name","surname"]   // dynamical array ( parameter to show )
```

in template :

```
<% for(i=0 ;i<sorters.length(); i++ ){ %>
   <h2><%= sorters[0] %></h2>   // its <%= 'name' %> with quotes 
<% } %>
```

as result i got

> name,
>   surname

i need get

> P,
>   a

As result i get values from Sorters[array] not model values:

Some examples

1.

```
name: "P",
surname: "a",
sorters: ["name"]
```

> P

2.

```
name: "P",
surname: "a",
sorters: ["surname","name"]
```

> a, P

With this code in template i dont have a `values from models` but string text from my array and my view instead of  attributes from model show labels

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for...

Comment: @EmileBergeron When i use For on template instead of values of name and surname  i get text "name" , "surname"

Comment: Clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that `sorters` returns a value which appears to be equal to another field in the model, you wish to **dynamically return that field**.

There's a few ways to do this, probably the best is to provide the `variable` option when creating the template ([docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template)). See example below:

```js
var model = new Backbone.Model({
  name: "P",
  surname: "a",
  sorters: ["name","surname"]
});

var tmp = _.template($('#template').html(), {variable: 'data'});
$('#result').html(tmp(model.attributes));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/template">
<% for(i=0; i < data.sorters.length; i++ ){ %>
   <h2><%= data[data.sorters[i]] %></h2>
<% } %>
</script>
<div id="result"/>
```

Also, better to use `each` rather than a for loop:

```
<% _.each(data.sorters, function(sorter) { %>
   <h2><%= data[sorter] %></h2>
<% }) %>
```